# tap-to-click with second finger

Tags: touchpad, 20.10, tap-to-click

I was wondering if there is a way to enable tap-to-click with a second finger. i.e using my index finger to move the mouse then tap-to-click with my middle finger while my index is still on the track pad.

My trackpad can do this as I used to have windows and it worked perfectly. I also currently have gestures enabled and they work perfectly.

I have ubuntu 20.10. Please let me know if you need any other info. I'm not sure what you might need.

I have had a look in "dconf" in /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad to no avail. I have also tried to search for solutions but i can only find standard tap-to-click settings.

Comment: well don't know the exact way but first, you will have to disable 2-finger scrolling secondly, you have to set 2-finger click to left-click and boom. However, the problem is how will you do the right-click.

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way to have 2-finger-scroll as well as the second finger tap-to-click?